# Shortcut for plucking two attributes from an ActiveRecord object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a shorter way to do the following (

```
@user.employees.map { |e| { id: e.id, name: e.name } }
# => [{ id: 1, name: 'Pete' }, { id: 2, name: 'Fred' }]
```

`User` `has_many` employees. Both classes inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Two things I don't like about the above

1. It loads employees into memory before mapping,
2. It's verbose (subjective I guess).

Is there a better way?

Comment: any reason to build a hash instead of working with Employee instances (with only those two columns loaded with a `select`)?

Comment: Yeah I know it's kinda contrived. I just noticed the `pluck` method and it seems to me that there should be a pluck for more than one attribute.

Comment: there is an open issue for pluck with more than 1 attribute: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5472. Also, check this: https://github.com/ernie/valium

Comment: Cool, thanks. Interesting gem and glad to see I'm 7 months behind the curve on Rails!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

see @jamesharker's solution: from ActiveRecord >= 4, `pluck` accepts multiple arguments:

```
@user.employees.pluck(:id, :name)
```

**PREVIOUS ANSWER:**

for a single column in rails >= 3.2, you can do :

```
@user.employees.pluck(:name)
```

... but as you have to pluck two attributes, you can do :

```
@user.employees.select([:id, :name]).map {|e| {id: e.id, name: e.name} } 
# or map &:attributes, maybe
```

if you *really* need lower-level operation, just look at the [source of #pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck), that uses `select_all`

Comment: doesn't select take an array of attributes?

Comment: Thank you for this. Coming from a 4.x app to a 3.2 app. Forgot about this. Was banging my head against the wall. Arghhhhh for old apps.

Comment: you're welcome ;). See also @NNA's answer, seems to address your concern.

Comment: You can pass args to select without an array: `@user.employees.select(:id, :name)`

Answer (score 42):

In ActiveRecord >= 4 [pluck](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/68aebd489566ee514d86765c0d5dceb7feb7aacf/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb#L123) accepts multiple arguments so this example would become:

```
@user.employees.pluck(:id, :name)
```

Comment: Right, but that returns an `array` without the keys; e.g.: `[[1, 'Pete'], [[2, 'Fred']]` as opposed to a `hash` which OP is looking for: `[{ id: 1, name: 'Pete' }, { id: 2, name: 'Fred' }]`

Comment: Any ideia of how to get [{ id: 1, name: 'Pete' }, { id: 2, name: 'Fred' }] without map?

Answer (score 8):

If you are stuck with Rails 3 you can add [this](http://meltingice.net/2013/06/11/pluck-multiple-columns-rails/) `.pluck_all` extension : http://meltingice.net/2013/06/11/pluck-multiple-columns-rails/

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to:

```
@user.employees.select(:id, :name).as_json
#=> [{"id" => 1, "name" => "Pete"}, {"id" => 2, "name" => "Fred"}]
```

I can imagine that you'd rather have symbolized keys.
If that's the case use the `#symbolize_keys` method.

```
@user.employees.select(:id, :name).as_json.map(&:symbolize_keys)
#=> [{id: 1, name: "Pete"}, {id: 2, name: "Fred"}]
```

See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json

Answer (score 0):

Add this monkey patch which provides the multi columns pluck functionality in Rails 3.

```
# config/initializers/pluck_all.rb

if Rails.version[0] == '3'
  ActiveRecord::Relation.class_eval do
    def pluck(*args)
      args.map! do |column_name|
        if column_name.is_a?(Symbol) && column_names.include?(column_name.to_s)
          "#{connection.quote_table_name(table_name)}.#{connection.quote_column_name(column_name)}"
        else
          column_name.to_s
        end
      end

      relation = clone
      relation.select_values = args
      klass.connection.select_all(relation.arel).map! do |attributes|
        initialized_attributes = klass.initialize_attributes(attributes)
        attributes.map do |key, attr|
          klass.type_cast_attribute(key, initialized_attributes)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Rename the method from `pluck` to `pluck_all` if you dont want to override the original `pluck` functionality

Answer (score 0):

In terms of making a rails 3 method that behaves the same as the Rails 4 pluck with multiple columns. This outputs a similar array (rather than a hashed key value collection). This should save a bit of pain if you ever come to upgrade and want to clean up the code.

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Relation
    def pluck_all(*args)
      args.map! do |column_name|
        if column_name.is_a?(Symbol) && column_names.include?(column_name.to_s)
          "#{connection.quote_table_name(table_name)}.#{connection.quote_column_name(column_name)}"
        else
          column_name.to_s
        end
      end

      relation = clone
      relation.select_values = args
      klass.connection.select_all(relation.arel).map! do |attributes|
        initialized_attributes = klass.initialize_attributes(attributes)
        attributes.map do |key, attribute|
          klass.type_cast_attribute(key, initialized_attributes)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Standing on the shoulders of giants and all

Answer (score 0):

The `pluck_all` method worked well until I'm going to upgrade from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4.

Here is a gem [pluck_all](https://github.com/khiav223577/pluck_all) to solve this, making `pluck_all` method support not only in Rails 3 but in Rails 4 and Rails 5. Hope this will help those who are going to upgrade rails version.